# update checkbox selected in javascript func in iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, checkbox, uiwebview

I want to update the selected value of checkbox for javascript function in iOS.
This is the HTML code for checkbox:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='displayraw' value='yes' selected='true' >
```

I want to change the `selected= "false" or "true"` when checkbox is checked or unchecked.

And here is my code: I used the webview to run submit function but cannot successful. I can change the value for textbox but cannot change the selected value for check box. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

```
NSString* temp = [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
                      [NSString stringWithFormat:
                       @"document.getElementsByName('%@')[0].selected='%@'",elementName, value]];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Checkboxes in HTML are `checked` *NOT* `selected`.**

So if you simply change your code to something like this:

*(notice how I have changed "selected" to "checked" in both examples):*

**Example HTML:**

```
  <input type='checkbox' name='displayraw' value='yes' checked='checked' />
```

**Example Objective-C:**

```
NSString* temp = [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
                      [NSString stringWithFormat:
                       @"document.getElementsByName('%@')[0].checked='%@'",elementName, value]];
```

So if you make sure that your javascript string in Objective-C is being evaluated like this:

```
// use this
document.getElementsByName('displayraw')[0].checked = true;
```

Then it should check your checkbox.

**UPDATE** ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

**To uncheck an 'checked' checkbox use:**

```
document.getElementsByName('displayraw')[0].checked = false;
```

**To check an 'unchecked' checkbox, use:**

```
document.getElementsByName('displayraw')[0].checked = true;
```

**[SEE THIS JAVASCRIPT IN ACTION VIA JSFIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/x9466jr9/2/)**

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for quick reply but my HTML is defined by other people.This is exactly HTML <input type='checkbox' name='displayraw' value='yes' checked selected='true' > There is "checked" but it is the text. When checkbox is uncheck, the "checked" text is removed. Is there any way to update it? thanks

Comment: See my updates and the updated fiddle. In your case you want to set the "checked" status using the `true` of `false` options show in the updated. Hope this helps!